# Why HMS Location Kit in React Native gives java.lang.NullPointerException:Attempt to invoke virtual method ' android.location.Location.toString()'?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

React Native in HMS Location Kit gives below error while building the project in Android Studio.
java.lang.NullPointerException:Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.location.Location.toString()' on a null object

Comment: How do you retrieve the null `Location` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue occur when

> getLastLocation

provides null value and there could be below reasons for the same :

- Location permission not given.
- Device location is not enabled.
- Device cache is clear.

Also, it is recommended to use location update API along with

> Get Last Location to prevent empty cache location issue.